# Ajax POST data, how to Split data?

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending `date` through Ajax and expecting two values in return (id, amount). For example, id=1, amount=100 but as a result i am getting 1100. How can i split values to 1 and 100? This is what i have tried so far. Last resort posting here, no relevant solution found despite hours of search.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date1').on('change',function(){

        var dateID = $(this).val();

        if (dateID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'dashboardData.php',
                data: {
                    'date1': dateID
                },
                success: function(html) {                         
                   $('#dailyExpense2').html(html);

                   console.log(html);    
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `expense` WHERE Date = '$today'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

$dailyID =  $row1['id'];
$dailyExpense =  $row1['amount'];
```

Comment: I don't see any return from PHP part, no echo or return. Could you show us the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX receives the data which was printed out on the PHP standard output (like, with print, or echo). However, you can format how it is echoed out, either a standarized way like json

```
$array[] = array("dailyID" => $dailyID, "dailyExpense" => $dailyExpanse);
print json_encode($array,[options_might_be_needed]);
return;
```

or a simple way, like separating them with commas

```
print $dailyID.",".$dailyExpanse;
return;
```

And then writing a receiving end at JavaScript, in the former case

```
var array = JSON.parse(html);
```

and the latter case

```
var array = html.split(",");
```

Then you can reach your individual data in associative arrays (named array).

Of course, there are many more methods, but almost all of them break down telling the scripts where does one instance of data ends, or where does it start.

Comment: Thanks a Million kry, i can sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

Send a request with JSON data format and get with JSON object result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#date1').on('change',function(){
            var dateID = $(this).val();
            if(dateID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'dashboardData.php',
                    data:{'date1':dateID},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);      
                        $('#dailyExpense2').html(response.id+'-'+response.amount);                      
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change PHP code with below code

```
$sqlQry = "SELECT * FROM `expense` WHERE Date = '".$today."'";
$resultQry = mysqli_query($link,$sqlQry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultQry);

$dailyID =  $row[0]['id'];

$dailyExpense =  $row[0]['amount'];

echo json_encode('id'=>$dailyID,'amount'=>$dailyExpense);

exit;
```